# App crash when button is pressed

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have 39 items(animations, animation Sounds, image sounds) and each animation frames has 50 images (i.e., 39x50). if you consider 'brushing' means i have the word brushing sound, brushing animation (50), their animation sounds.  All 39 items has these three parts.  These animation i will call sequentially using for loop.

```
//methodB
- (void) methodB {
[self animationSound];

if (counter == 0){
    NSMutableArray *dashBoy = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
        butterfly = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"brush_%d.png", i];
        if ((image = [UIImage imageNamed:butterfly]))
            [dashBoy addObject:image];
    }

    [stgImageView setAnimationImages:dashBoy];
    [stgImageView setAnimationDuration:3.9f];
    [stgImageView startAnimating];

    }

    .
    .
    .

if(counter == 38) {
    NSMutableArray *dashBoy38 = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {
        butterfly = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"wash_%d.png", i];
        if ((image = [UIImage imageNamed:butterfly]))
            [dashBoy38 addObject:image];
    }

    [stgImageView setAnimationImages:dashBoy38];
    [stgImageView setAnimationDuration:2.0f];
    [stgImageView startAnimating];
}

}
```

Then i have two buttons next and previous, my actions is if i click the next button the image will change and 2 sec delay play their corresponding animations with animation sounds and click the previous button vice versa.

```
//next and previous function
-(void)btnClicked:(UIButton*)btn{
[stgImageView stopAnimating];
[myTimer invalidate];

if (btn.tag==1) {
    counter++;
    if (counter == [stgImageArray count])
        counter = 0;
        [stgImageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[stgImageArray objectAtIndex:counter]]];
    stgText.text= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [stgTextArray objectAtIndex:counter]];

    myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0f target:self selector:@selector(methodB) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}
else{
    counter--;
    if (counter < 0)
        counter = 39;
        [stgImageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[stgImageArray objectAtIndex:counter]]];
    stgText.text= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [stgTextArray objectAtIndex:counter]];

    myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0f target:self selector:@selector(methodB) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

}
}
```

Problem is if click the next or previous button continuously the app will crash in my iPad.  If anybody tell me how to manage those 39 items with their animation and animation sounds.

I want if i click next button image will change and after 2 sec animation play and animation sound and click another time previous animation will stop and change image with their animation and so on.

Comment: Can you run with debugger and give the crash reason ?

Comment: no how to run with debug

Comment: You can run on your iPad from Xcode and debug the app while running. That gives you more details on the crash. Otherwise it is hard to help.